# Macro to swap selections

Tags: macros, emeditor

As an author, I frequently have to swap two words, phrases or sentences. I do that by dragging and dropping or by using the clipboard history, or by retyping, all of which are cumbersome and prone to mistakes.

1. Is there a command or macro to automatically swap two selections?

Example: after selecting 'short' and 'simple' in the sentence 'This is a short and simple example' and swapping them, the sentence would become 'This is a simple and short example'

2. For simple word swapping, it would be handy if such a function would default to selecting the words with a cursor (empty selection) in them.

Example: place two cursors in the above sentence, one in the word 'simple' and one in 'short', and they'll be automatically selected and reversed.

3. For swapping a word and a phrase, it would be handy if I could select the word by Ctrl-clicking and the phrase by dragging to have it automatically selected (that is, a combination of 1 and 2).
4. More generally, I would like to be able to invert any number of selections of any length anywhere in a document.

Simple example: the text 'a b c d e f g' with the a, the c, the e and the g selected becomes 'g b e d c f a'.

Obviously swapping two selections is a special case of reversing any number of selections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a **JavaScript** macro for **EmEditor** to swap multiple selections or words at the cursor positions.

```
Redraw = false;  // optimize for speed
CombineHistory =  true; // combine Undo
nMax = document.selection.Count;  // retrieve the number of selections
ax = Array( nMax );
ax2 = Array( nMax );
ay = Array( nMax );
ay2 = Array( nMax );
as = Array( nMax );
for( i = 0; i < nMax; ++i ) {  // retrieve position of each selection
    ax[i] = document.selection.GetTopPointX( eePosLogical, i + 1 );
    ax2[i] = document.selection.GetBottomPointX( eePosLogical, i + 1 );
    ay[i] = document.selection.GetTopPointY( eePosLogical, i + 1 );
    ay2[i] = document.selection.GetBottomPointY( eePosLogical, i + 1 );
}
for( i = 0; i < nMax; ++i ) {  // retrieve word text and positions
    if( ax[i] == ax2[i] && ay[i] == ay2[i] ) {
        document.selection.SetActivePoint( eePosLogical, ax[i], ay[i] );  // set cursor position
        document.selection.SelectWord();  // select a word
        ax[i] = document.selection.GetTopPointX( eePosLogical );    // retrieve selection position
        ax2[i] = document.selection.GetBottomPointX( eePosLogical );
        as[i] = document.selection.Text;  // retrieve selected text
    }
    else {
        document.selection.SetActivePoint( eePosLogical, ax[i], ay[i] );
        document.selection.SetActivePoint( eePosLogical, ax2[i], ay2[i], true );
        as[i] = document.selection.Text;  // retrieve selected text
    }
}
for( i = nMax - 1; i >= 0; --i ) {   // set a selection from bottom to top
    document.selection.SetActivePoint( eePosLogical, ax[i], ay[i] );
    document.selection.SetActivePoint( eePosLogical, ax2[i], ay2[i], true );
    document.selection.Text = as[nMax - i - 1];  // set new text
}
```

To run this, save this code as, for instance, `Macro.jsee`, and then select this file from **Select...** in the **Macros** menu. Finally, select **Run Macro.jsee** in the **Macros** menu while multiple selections are made.

Comment: This macro swaps just the first word of each selection, not the selections as a whole. Example: select 'a b' and 'c d' in 'a b c d' and swap. Result: c b a d. Expected: c d a b.

Comment: I thought that you wanted to retrieve a word at each cursor position. I've updated my answer allowing you to retrieve a selection if already selected, or a word if not selected, at each cursor position. Please feel free to develop the macro for your goal.

Comment: Elegant, intuitive and versatile. Reverses horizontal, vertical and empty selections in any combination. I have never seen this in any editor. It would be an asset to EmEditor core, under Edit > Advanced.